# Yii PHP Command Line App for extraction of Microdata values NOT working

Tags: php, xpath, microdata

I want to extract Microdata values.

I use a Yii App runned from the command line, using Putty.

The following code does not generate any output;

in $this->input->html i store an entire html document source;

I think that somewhere at `$content = new DOMXPath($dom);` something cracks; dont know why

If anyone knows, please give a hand;

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$html = $this->input->html;

$html = <<<HTML
echo $html;
HTML;

        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

        echo $html;

        $content = new DOMXPath($dom);

        print_r($content);

        // find price
        try {
            echo '1'.$this->getMicrodataAttribute($content, 'http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer', 'price');
            $this->output->productPrice = $this->getMicrodataAttribute($content, 'http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer', 'price');
            //echo 'result output product price: '.$this->output->productPrice.PHP_EOL;
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
        // find title
        try {

            $this->output->productTitle = $this->getMicrodataAttribute($content, 'http://data-vocabulary.org/Product', 'name');
            if (!$this->output->productTitle)
                if (preg_match("#<title>(.+)<\/title>#iU", $this->input->html, $t)) {
                    $this->output->productTitle = trim($t[1]);
                }
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
```

and this is the function that should extract the microdata values:

```
public function getMicrodataAttribute($content, $itemtype, $itemprop) {
    $tags = $content->query("//*[@itemtype=\"$itemtype\"]//*[@itemprop=\"$itemprop\"]");
    //print_r($tags);
    if ($tags) {
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            //die('dd');
            if (!$tag->getAttribute('content')) {
                return $tag->nodeValue;
            }
            return $tag->getAttribute('content');
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code where you get your `html` text into a `DOMDocument` is a bit convoluted. Maybe there's an error hiding in there. Try this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $this->input->html );
$content = new DOMXPath($dom);
print_r($content);
```

Note that I removed the `@` from the `loadHTML` method. With this, you can see if it throws any errors.

Comment: so, after a day of code inspection, line by line, i found the error; it was somewhere else, far away from this code; this code works great; 10x for answering